# Xcode build folder appearing in svn

Tags: xcode, svn, versions

I am currently working on a project which is included in a versions(svn)repository. Although I'm not sure, I think I might have changed some settings in Xcode, affecting the way the source control saves the build folder in the repository. I was told it is a bad practice to commit the build folder, and asked why have I done that, but I had no answer at the moment. A screen will elucidate this more clear:

[image: versions screenshot]

Even if I tried to delete (or ignore) those files from the repository, they are still created after I build the project. How should I proceed in order to prevent those build folders appear in versions' project tree?

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding versioned folder to ignore-pattern does not affect data in SVN
2. You must ignore and remove folder from SVN, but keep it locally

For CLI it will be `svn pe ...` in the parent of build folder and `svn rm build --keep-local` (I don't know XCode GUI's equivalents)